# Exception handling in a switch

Tags: java, exception, switch-statement

The following code is in a while loop which then houses a switch as such:

```
  System.out.println("Enter in a selection.");
  System.out.println("Enter \"1\" for a default selection of die");
  System.out.println("Enter \"2\" for a custom number of sides.");
  //try the input to see if its an integer
  try {
  selection = sc.nextInt();
  } catch (NumberFormatException e){
      System.out.print("Your selection can only be an integer!");
   } 
 switch (selection){
   case1:
   ...
   break;

   case2:
   ...
   break;

   default:
   ...
   //yell at them
   continue;
  }
```

I already have a default selection in the switch so that if a user enters in an invalid number like 4 (since there are only 2 cases) that it brings them back to the beginning of the loop. So, the issue is handling the exception. The exception does not get handled with the following above code and I don't know why. The try is housing the offending code.

As always, please ask for clarification if needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should `continue` on the exception as there is no point in going ahead do the `switch` on the `selection` if the exception occurred.

```
} catch (InputMismatchException e){
    System.out.print("Your selection can only be an integer!");
    sc.nextLine();
    continue;
}
```

---

The way you have it right now, if the exception were to occur you would be switching the old stale value held by `selection`.

---

But the main problem in your code is that the [`nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) method doesn't throw the `NumberFormatException`, instead it throws the `InputMismatchException`.

So you are trying to catch the **wrong exception**.

Comment: Throwing out the last selection certainly would be a good idea. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

The reason exception is not handled when you enter `4` is that `4` is a valid integer and `nextInt()` will not raise `NumberFormatException` exception.

You'd better enclose the `switch` in the `try` block.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would put your input (and the try/catch block that goes with it) in its own, separate method.  Return a boolean (true = valid integer) or a value that's out of range (perhaps "-1", depending on your program).

IMHO...

Answer (score 1):

[**Scanner#nextInt()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) doesn't throw `NumberFormatException`

`Scans the next token of the input as an int. An invocation of this method of the form nextInt() behaves in exactly the same way as the invocation  nextInt(radix) , where  radix< is the default radix of this scanner.`

```
 return the int scanned from the input
 throws InputMismatchException
         if the next token does not match the <i>Integer</i>
          regular expression, or is out of range
 throws NoSuchElementException if input is exhausted
 throws IllegalStateException if this scanner is closed
```

**Your exception handling seems right, with only issue that you are catching wrong exception.** Please catch `InputMismatchException` and other two.

e.g. below:

```
    try {
          selection = sc.nextInt();
      } catch (InputMismatchException e){
          System.out.print("Your selection can only be an integer!");
      }
```

Also you may want to put the above code in a while loop as below:

```
       boolean validInput = false;
       while(!validInput){
     try {
          selection = sc.nextInt();
              validInput = true;
      } catch (InputMismatchException e){
          System.out.print("Your selection can only be an integer!");
      }
       }
```

**This will repeatedly ask for input until a number is entered.**

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a `Scanner`, you can use the `hasNextInt()` method (and equivalents for other data types) rather than crashing and burning via exception:

```
while (some_condition) {
  System.out.println("Enter in a selection.");
  System.out.println("Enter \"1\" for a default selection of die");
  System.out.println("Enter \"2\" for a custom number of sides.");
  //try the input to see if its an integer
  if (!sc.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println("You must enter an integer!");
    continue;
  }
  selection = sc.nextInt();

  switch (selection){
   case 1:
   ...
   break;

   case 2:
   ...
   break;

   default:
   ...
   //yell at them
   continue;
  }
}
```

As [Bhesh Gurung said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13215341/129655), if you're in a loop, you should just use `continue` to go back to the beginning, like you do in the `default` case.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to really handle the exception in the 'switch' statement, you need to expand the scope of the try-catch block:

```
  System.out.println("Enter in a selection.");
  System.out.println("Enter \"1\" for a default selection of die");
  System.out.println("Enter \"2\" for a custom number of sides.");
  //try the input to see if its an integer
  try {
  selection = sc.nextInt();

  switch (selection){
   case1:
   ...
   break;

   case2:
   ...
   break;

   default:
   ...
   //yell at them
   throw new NumberFormatException("Yelling message");
   continue;
  }
 } catch (NumberFormatException e){
      System.out.print("Your selection can only be an integer!");
 }
```